# Prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{1+\ln x}$ does not belong to $L^p(1,\infty)$ except for $p=2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the function $f(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{1+\ln x}$ does not belong to $L^p(1,\infty)$ except for $p=2$.

It is easy to directly see that if $p=2$ , $\int^{\infty}_1 |f|^2=1< \infty.$

For the general case and using the fact that $1+ \ln x \leq x $ I can say $$\int^{\infty}_1 |f|^p= \int^{\infty}_1 \left|\frac{x^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{1+\ln x}\right|^p \geq \int^{\infty}_1 \left|\frac{x^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{x}\right|^p = \int^{\infty}_1 x^{-3p/2}=\frac{1}{{\frac{-3p}{2}+1}} \left(-1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{-3p}{2}+1} \right)$$

Clearly if ${\frac{-3p}{2}+1} > 0$, i.e. $p<2/3$ (which NEVER happens in $L^p$ thory) , the limit does not exist, which implies that $f$ does not belong to the corresponding $L^p(1,\infty)$.

Therefore I need a better inequality , different from $1+ \ln x \leq x $, to get the correct direction. I appreciate your hints already.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>1$, $f(x)>0$.  Therefore if $1 < p < q < \infty$, 
$\int_1^\infty |f(x)|^p\,dx < \int_1^\infty |f(x)|^q\,dx $, and what you are trying to prove is impossible.

Comment: This is a claim in Royden's book, page 143. I exactly copy here what he says : $f$ belongs to $L^p(1,\infty)$ if and only if $p=2$

Comment: That's strange !!!

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : thanks for checking.  I like his books.  What you're trying to prove really seems impossible to me, though.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a better upper bound will not solve the problem, because $1+\ln x\ge 1$, so even if you replace $1+\ln x$ by $1$,  you get $\int_1^\infty |x^{-1/2}|^p$, which is finite for $p>2$.